# How to find how many times numbers fit into a large number

Tags: python, excel, matlab

I cannot think of an efficient way to check the best way to put two numbers that equal a larger number. Let me explain it with an example

```
no1 = 4;
no2 = 6;

finalValue = 26;
```

the algorithm would then find that the best option to get the final number from the two others, so `5*4 + 6 = 26` or `6*3 + 2*4 = 26`. (Ideal case) Basically the idea is to go as little over the finalValue as possible. Could anyone please point me to the right direction please? :)

The programming languages I am using are python, matlab or ideally excel :)

Comment: How is 54 + 6 = 26 and 63 + 2*4 = 26

Comment: My apologies @Sujay Now it should be clearer

Comment: If Excel, were you thinking of a formula answer (if possible), or VBA? Also, I wasn't quite clear if for a non-exact fit you were looking for one that 'went  a little over' (like 2*6+4*4) rather than one that went just under (like 2*6+3*4).

Comment: @TomSharpe I do not have tons of experience in Excel, so I cannot really choose between the two. As I know more about formulas than VBA's, I would say Formula. Evidently I know programming, so I can create a program that exports an excel table :) As for overshooting, I just wanted the smallest difference of the total value from the wanted value, but it has to go above. The way it is selected has no effect. Maybe it would be best to have the smallest amount of 'multiplication' but in the end it does not make that much of a difference. I hope that cleared up some stuff :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working solution (using Matlab) with two variants, depending on (when a perfect solution does not exist) if you want the closest match (in an absolute sense) or the closest match above finalValue (as what you originally asked for was "to go as little over the finalValue as possible"). Comment out the "results=" lines accordingly, currently the second one overrides the first. The function which finds the solutions is getSolutions, the part above is just to set the variables and print the results. (To test the code when there exist close but imperfect matches, try changing no2 to 12.)

```
no1=4;
no2=6;
finalValue = 26;

solutions = getSolutions( no1, no2, finalValue );
if( no1*solutions(1,1)+no2*solutions(1,2)==finalValue )
    s = 'a perfect solution';
else
    s = sprintf( 'closest to %d', finalValue );
end

for i=1:size(solutions,1)
    fprintf( '%d*%d + %d*%d = %d is %s.\n', solutions(i,1), no1, solutions(i,2), no2, solutions(i,1)*no1+solutions(i,2)*no2, s );
end

function solutions = getSolutions(a,b,c)
    % looking for solutions to ax+by=c, assuming that a,b,c,x,y are positive integers
    x = 0:ceil(c/a);
    y = 0:ceil(c/b);
    [xgrid,ygrid] = meshgrid(x,y); xgrid = xgrid(:); ygrid=ygrid(:);
    results = abs( a * xgrid + ygrid * b - c ); % this looks for the best results that are as close as possible to c, even if lower.
    results = a * xgrid(:) + ygrid(:) * b - c; % this looks for the best results that are equal as low as possible *above* c, as asked by OP.
    closest = min( results( results >= 0 ) );
    idx = find( results == closest );        
    solutions = [xgrid( idx ), ygrid( idx )];
end
```

If this is meant to search in a large integers set (say with integers greater than 1000), doing it the above way would work but might not scale well as it involves creating an (approximately) NxN matrix, where N is the largest possible integer that could solve the problem. In this case, you would be better off with integer-constrained optimization and your best shot might be along the lines of:

```
solution = intlinprog([no1,no2],1:2,[-no1,-no2],-finalValue,[],[],[0,0]);
```

This only finds one solution, but it involves a "smarter" optimization (instead of brute force) which should scale well. For example, inputing the equivalent values `4*1e5`, `6*1e5` and `26*1e5` oviously should produce the same solutions. The size of the brute force approach however would be prohibitive, whereas the optimization approach works flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a Python script that does the job. Firstly, it checks whether it is possible to fit either number exactly in the final one. If that isn't possible I've implemented a brute force manner to come to the (best) answer.

I start increasing the multiple of the first number and see if I can exactly complement it with a multiple for the second number to fit the final number. If that's not possible I check the difference between the first+second and the final number, and see if that's less than the best difference seen. If so, I store these in variables. Then, I do exactly the same for the second number (start increasing and complement with first).

The code can definitely be improved and I'm pretty sure there is an efficient algorithm for this. I was just curious what a quick and dirty brute force approach would look like. Hopefully, it will help you find an efficient approach.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

first = int(sys.argv[1])
second = int(sys.argv[2])
third = int(sys.argv[3])

print(f"How many times do {first} and {second} fit in {third}?")

# Determine whether the first number exactly fits
if third % first == 0:
    print(f"{first} fits exactly {int(third/first)} times in {third}")
    sys.exit()

# Determine whether the second number exactly fits
if third % second == 0:
    print(f"{second} fits exactly {int(third/second)} times in {third}")
    sys.exit()

best_difference = None
first_best = None
second_best = None

# Increase the multiple of the first and see whether the second exactly fits the remainder
for i in range(int(third/first) + 1):
    remain = third - ((i+1) * first)
    k = remain / second

    if remain % second == 0:
        print(f"Exact fit: {i+1} * {first} + {int(k)} * {second}")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        remain_minus_K = remain - round(k)*second
        diff = abs(remain) if abs(remain) < abs(remain_minus_K) else abs(remain_minus_K)

        if best_difference == None or best_difference > diff:
            best_difference = diff
            first_best = i+1
            second_best = 0 if abs(remain) < abs(remain_minus_K) else int(round(k))


# Increase the multiple of the first and see whether the first exactly fits the remainder
for i in range(int(third/second)):
    remain = third - ((i+1) * second)
    k = remain / first

    if remain % first == 0:
        print(f"Exact fit: {i+1} * {second} + {k} * {first}")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        remain_minus_K = remain - round(k)*first
        diff = abs(remain) if abs(remain) < abs(remain_minus_K) else abs(remain_minus_K)
            
        if best_difference == None or best_difference > diff:
            best_difference = diff
            first_best = 0 if abs(remain) < abs(remain_minus_K) else int(round(k))
            second_best = i+1

print(f"No exact fit. Closest: {first_best} * {first} + {second_best} * {second} = {first_best * first + second_best * second}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wondering if this could be done with an array formula in Excel...

Method: work through the possible multiples 1..i..floor(z/x) of the first multiplicand where x is the first multiplicand, y is the second multiplicand and z is the target number. For each one, find the difference d between i*x and z, modulo y. The overshoot is then given by y-d, except where d is zero, when it is zero. Candidates for best fit are those pairs where the overshoot is equal to the minimum overshoot (in the first few examples the minimum overshoot is zero so there is at least one exact solution).

```
=LET(x,A2,y,B2,z,C2,
seq,SEQUENCE(1,z/x-0.1),
modDiff,MOD(z-seq*x,y),
diff,IF(modDiff=0,0,y-modDiff),
minDiff,MIN(diff),
FILTER(seq&"X"&x&","&QUOTIENT(z-seq*x+diff,y)&"X"&y,diff=minDiff))
```

Here are a few examples:

[image]

The only 'trick' is to subtract a small amount from the target number (z) when working out the sequence length to avoid the case where the first number fits exactly and you have zero times the second number (eg if the target is 24, you could have 6X4+0X6) - I'm assuming you don't want that one.

---

Here is a VBA solution:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Multiples()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim row As Long
Dim x As Long, y As Long, z As Long
Dim n As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim overshoot As Long, minOvershoot As Long

Set sht = ActiveSheet

lastRow = sht.Cells(sht.rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row

With sht
For row = 2 To lastRow

    ' Assign values and do some checking
    
    x = Cells(row, 1)
    y = Cells(row, 2)
    z = Cells(row, 3)

    If x > z Or y > z Then GoTo continue:
    
    ' Avoid case where z is n*x + 0*y
    
    If z Mod x = 0 Then
        n = z \ x - 1
    Else
        n = z \ x
    End If
            
    ' Find min overshoot
    
    minOvershoot = y
    
    For i = 1 To n
    overshoot = getOvershoot(i, x, y, z)
    If overshoot < minOvershoot Then minOvershoot = overshoot
    Next i
    
    Cells(row, 4) = minOvershoot
    
    ' Find best fit
    
    j = 4
    For i = 1 To n
    overshoot = getOvershoot(i, x, y, z)
    If overshoot = minOvershoot Then
        j = j + 1
        Cells(row, j) = i
        j = j + 1
        Cells(row, j) = (z - i * x + overshoot) \ y
    End If
    Next i
    
continue:
Next row
End With

End Sub

Function getOvershoot(i As Long, x As Long, y As Long, z As Long) As Long
    Dim shortfall As Long, remainder As Long, overshoot As Long
    shortfall = z - i * x
    remainder = shortfall Mod y

    If remainder = 0 Then
        overshoot = 0
    Else
        overshoot = y - remainder
    End If
    
    getOvershoot = overshoot

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: For some reason, I do not get the printed values of x, I just get a !NAME error... Also, how would I go about getting solely the 3 before 3X6 and 2 from 2X4 in separate cells (1 cell returns 3, the other - 2)

Comment: It sounds as though your version of Excel doesn't support the Let function and/or the Sequence function. Both of these need Excel 365. It would be possible to re-cast the formula for earlier versions of Excel and change it so that it reports the two multiples in separate cells, but you would be talking about a very long formula and starting to think that VBA (or Python or Matlab) might be a better option. Also it wouldn't be a spill formula, you would need to pull it across as well as down.

Comment: VBA solution added.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(finalValue%no1 == 0){
return finalValue/no1;
} else if(finalValue%no1 - no2 == 0){
return finalValue/no1 +1;
} else if(finalValue%no2 == 0){
return finalValue/no2;
} else if(finalValue%no2 - no1 == 0){
return finalValue/no2 +1;
} else {
//it's not an exact fit
}
```

FYI: The % symbol in Python is called the Modulo Operator. It returns the remainder of dividing the left hand operand by right hand operand. It's used to get the remainder of a division problem.